Android - Firebase Crashlytics's dashboard is not opening
I’ve added Firebase Crashlytics dependencies to my Android application, and while the Firebase initialization seems to be working fine (e.g., FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this) is called in onCreate()), I am not seeing any crash reports on the Firebase Crashlytics dashboard, even after intentionally throwing a runtime error.
I have added the required dependencies and applied the Crashlytics plugin in the build.gradle file. The ProGuard rules for Crashlytics have also been configured. I tried force-sending logs using FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().sendUnsentReports(), but the dashboard remains inactive.
What could be the possible reasons for this, and how can I resolve the issue to ensure crash reports are sent and displayed properly in the Crashlytics dashboard?
build.gralde(:app)
plugins{
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.firebase.crashlytics)
}
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.firebase.crashlytics)
}

build.gralde(:project)
plugins{
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.firebase.crashlytics) apply false
}

libs.version.toml
[versions]
firebase-bom = "33.2.0"
firebase-crashlytics = "3.0.2"

[libraries]
firebase-bom = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-bom", version.ref = "firebase-bom" }
firebase-analytics = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-analytics" }
firebase-messaging-ktx = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-messaging" }
firebase-crashlytics = {group = "com.google.firebase" , name="firebase-crashlytics"}

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "android-gradle-plugin" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
hilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt-android" }
compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }
firebase-crashlytics = {id = "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" , version.ref = "firebase-crashlytics"}


@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())

        KakaoSdk.init(this, getString(R.string.kakao_share_app_key))
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

          // dashboard is not showing !
            Firebase.crashlytics.recordException(throwable)  
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("APP CRASHED MANUALLY")
            FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().sendUnsentReports()
        }
    }
}

I expected the Firebase Crashlytics dashboard to be displayed.

Add to My Application
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

I found it here
link

Thank you for your response, Nguyễn Mạnh Cường.
Even after trying the suggestions mentioned, the issue wasn’t resolved, but I found the cause while making other attempts.
I initially thought that adding only the Firebase Crashlytics dependency would suffice, but the com.google.gms.google-services plugin was essential.
After adding that plugin, the problem was resolved.

The first part would be better suited as a comment under the previous answer, instead of being part of your answer. Can you [edit] it out, and place it as a comment instead?
